# expressjs 4.x and https, generate key and certificate

Tags: node.js, curl, express, https, supertest

I want to create an https server with express 4.x. Even if a lot of code found on google is based on express 3.x I think I made the port correctly.

Even if I tried to goole it is not very clear to me how to generate the keys. Without the key I'm expecting 401.

I tried with the script found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sandfox/1831932). But I'm keeping on receiving the error `Error: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT`.

I'd like to test it both with `curl`, [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request), and [super test](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest).

This is what actually I have:

#### server.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , https = require('https')
  , fs = require('fs');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./server/server-private-key.pem').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('./server/server-certificate.pem').toString();

var options = {
  key : privateKey
, cert : certificate
}
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    req.client.authorized ? 
        res.json({"status":"approved"}) : 
        res.json({"status":"denied"}, 401);
});

server = https.createServer(options,app);

var port = 12345;
server.listen(port, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
});
```

#### client.js

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 12345,
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    key: fs.readFileSync('./client/client-private-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./client/client-certificate.pem'),
    headers: {}
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('dudee');
    console.log(res);
});
req.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

With cURL you can use the `-k` flag to bypass the self-signed cert problem.

With `request` you can just set `rejectUnauthorized: false` in the request options.

Comment: ok.. with -k I get `{"status":"denied"}` that is what I want. But what about the `DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT `? and what about the keys generation?

Comment: You said you already generated the keys? You could set the `ca` on the server and client sides though.

Comment: probabilly I'm doing it wrong. Can you point me to a script for doing it?